# Doctrine Custom Discriminator map

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

So I am working on integrating Symfony 3 into a legacy codebase and for the most part everything is good. Unfortunately I am having some issue with single table inheritance with a funky discriminator. NOTE: I cannot change the schema (at least anytime soon) because it is tied into a lot of old code.

I have the classic Person -> Employee mapping. With this I have 2 tables:

- Company
- Person

that translate to 3 entities

- Company
- Person

  - Employee

This seems pretty straight forward except the only viable discriminator is company_id which is a column on person, denoting which company that person belongs to. If company_id = 1 it is an employee, otherwise it is just a normal person.

So as far as I can tell I would need a map that looks like this:

```
/**
 * @InheritanceType( "SINGLE_TABLE" )
 * @DiscriminatorColumn( name = "company_id", type = "integer" )
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *      1 = "Employee",
 *      2 = "Person",
 *      3 = "Person",
 *      ...
 *      5001 = "Person"
 *   })
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="person")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Person
{}
```

That way of mapping is impossible to maintain. I have looked around but I have not found a good solution to this. For now I am using a Mapped super class and then pointing both Person and Employee to the person table, which works from a code standpoint, but if I run schema validate it errors due to table name already exists. This makes it harder to maintain the mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly I'm not sure if something like that would be possible, because would be kinda crazy for generated queries (especially if you have a lot of records).

Another idea how to solve it, add new column (should't affect old application, because its not changing any of current fields) which will use trigger to populate and you use this one as discriminator. If that not possible, consider creating view with new field as discriminator.

Comment: hmm, I had a feeling it wouldn't be possible. A new column would be great, but some higher ups have vetoed that suggestion multiple times. A view might just work though. Thanks.

Comment: Then I think view will be your way to go.